How can I input data of list as a number in option declare function of \begin{tikzpicture}?
I have a list
list = {{2, 2, 2}, {8/3, 9/2, 7/2}};

I want to input elements of list into
\\ begin {tikzpicture}[
  declare  function = {a = "<>rep@toX[data[[n,1]]]<>"; 
    b = "<>rep@toX[data[[n,2]]]<>"; 
    h = "<>rep@toX[data[[n,3]]]<>";}] 
\\ end {tikzpicture}

I tried
Clear["Global`*"]
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
list = {{2, 2, 2}, {8/3, 9/2, 7/2}};
myfunction[{a_, b_, h_}] := {a, b, h};
data = myfunction /@ list;
rep[s_String] := StringReplace[s, "," -> ";"];
toX[e_] := 
 StringReplace[
  ToString[TeXForm[e]], {"\\frac" -> "\\dfrac", "\\}" -> ")", 
   "\\{" -> "("}]
fileName = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "data.tex"}]
If[FileExistsQ[fileName], DeleteFile[fileName]];
file = OpenWrite[fileName, PageWidth -> Infinity];
WriteString[file, 
  "\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n" <> 
   "\\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}\n" <> "\\begin{document}\n"];
Do[WriteString[file,
   "\\begin{ex}\n
\\begin{figure}[H]
\\centering
\\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=" <> rep@toX[data[[n, 1]]] <>
     ";b=" <> rep@toX[data[[n, 2]]] <> ";h=" <> 
    rep@toX[data[[n, 3]]] <> ";}] 
\\end{tikzpicture}
\\end{figure}
\n\\end{ex}\n
"], {n, 1, Length@data}];
WriteString[file, "\\end{document}\n"];
Close[file]

I got the LaTeX file
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
\begin{document}
\begin{ex}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=2;b=2;h=2;}] 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{ex}

\begin{ex}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=\dfrac{8}{3};b=\dfrac{9}{2};h=\dfrac{7}{2};}] 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{ex}

\end{document}

At the line
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=\dfrac{8}{3};b=\dfrac{9}{2};h=\dfrac{7}{2};}]

How  can I get
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=8/3;b=9/2;h=7/2;}]


That's a lot of unnecessary code for a fairly simple question :) Just don't use TeXForm, but use InputForm instead ...

The crux of this question is about creating a string based on a template and some arguments. The TeX stuff is a red herring, and the file write can easily be done with the resulting string. So, I'd approach this rather literally using a template object.
list = {{2, 2, 2}, {8/3, 9/2, 7/2}};
prettyList = Map[ToString@*InputForm, list, {-1}];

texTemplate =
  StringTemplate[
"\\begin{ex}\n
\\begin{figure}[H]
\\centering
\\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=`1`;b=`2`;h=`3`;}] 
\\end{tikzpicture}
\\end{figure}
\n\\end{ex}\n
"]

texChunks = TemplateApply[texTemplate, #] & /@ prettyList;

stringToWrite = StringJoin[texChunks]

Maybe you want StringRiffle if you need to put some extra spacing in the stringToWrite. At this point, you can do whatever you want with the stringToWrite.
